# Can't get notification payload from firebase-sw on Ionic PWA

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic3, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I've searched a lot for this problem that I'm stuck on for a week.
I have an Ionic PWA project that receive some notifications from firebase, I can receive the notifications with no problem and can get the payload on foreground (app is open), but I cant get the payload when the app is closed and I don't figure out what is goning on, so I came here to ask the masters to help me.

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
    var notificationTitle = 'Teste';
    var notificationOptions = {
      body: 'Background Message body.',
      tag: 'campanhas',
      data: payload.data,
      icon: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/hemotomobile-edeb9.appspot.com/o/logo.png?alt=media&token=4a9fc487-b8cf-4d3c-875c-774454ff6f50'
   };


   return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
  notificationOptions);
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
   event.notification.close();

   event.waitUntil(clients.matchAll({
     type: "window"
   }).then(function(clientList) {
     for (var i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++) {
       var client = clientList[i];
       if (client.url == '/' && 'focus' in client)
       return client.focus();
     }
     if (clients.openWindow)
      return clients.openWindow('/');
   }));
});
```

and on my provider for the notifications, I use this code:

```
public receiveMessage() {
  console.log('notification')
  this.messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
    console.log('payload',payload)
  });
}
```

I call this provider on my tabs-page:

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
  this.notification.receiveMessage()
}
```

So, can anyone help me to get the payload when the PWA is closed?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried by initializing  firebase in the service worker and using it ,

```
self.addEventListener("notificationclick", (event) => {
   //your code 
});

importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.7.0/firebase.js")
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.7.0/firebase-messaging.js")

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp({
'messagingSenderId': 'your sender id'
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  //your code
});

this.messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
   //your code
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclose', function (event) {
  self.registration.getNotifications().then(function (notifications) {
     notifications.forEach(function (notification) {
         notification.close()
     })
  });
})
```

I have tried by using above code in the service worker and it is showing notification when the application is closed , if you want to show the notification when the browser is closed make sure you have enabled the ***Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed*** option in chrome settings.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But the problem is read the payload when I click on the notification. I can show the notification when my app is closed but I can't get the payload on Ionic app. There's a way to pass some data from a Javascript file to the Angular?

Comment: as you are saying that , on notification click you are not able to get payload , it seems that there are some issues in firebase messaging library ,

Comment: try https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/102 , you can refer which says to define the addEvent listener of notification close at the beginning before we load the firebase import scripts ,that's why in the code that i have added for reference,  mentioned the notification close event listener is added in the beginning of the code

Comment: The click event are working fine but I can't get the payload data when I open my PWA. I can see the payload data on the console.log of the firebase-service-worker but I can't use the data on my angular project